# How can i access getter and setter function of Object?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

There is one object that has a property named password. This property is called by calling the set method. Then I defined the second setter method to the same property.But I want both the first setter method and the second setter method to work.For this, how can I access the first setter function?

```js
//constant code
var obj = {
  get password() {
            return this._password;
        },
  set password(val) {
            this._password = new TextEncoder().encode(val);
        }
}
```

```js
Object.defineProperty(obj,"password",{set:function(val){
//exectue first setter function of password
//execute second setter
this._password=val;}})
```

I can only modify the code.  I can't make any changes to the code either.

**How can I access first setter function?**

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "password");` - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep original version of setter to call it inside of your new version:

```js
const originalSetPassword = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "password").set;
Object.defineProperty(obj, "password", {
  set: function(val) {
    originalSetPassword.call(obj, val);
    this._password=val;
  }
});
```